# Error trying to migrate PG database hosted on Heroku -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Im getting this error when running `heroku run rake db:migrate` -> `ERROR:  column "frequency" cannot be cast automatically to type integer` I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in order to fix this error. Here is my schema local that works fine when I migrated:

## schema:

```
create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "attachment"
    t.integer  "finished_count"
    t.datetime "start_at"
    t.datetime "end_at"
    t.integer  "frequency"
    t.integer  "status",         default: 0
    t.index ["status"], name: "index_assignments_on_status"
  end
```

Cannot I not use `integer` as a type with PG? if not, what should I do instead?

Comment: Could you also post the migration file here in order to find the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your migration, which you should post.   A likely cause is that the frequency column already has data in it.  Therefore PG cannot blindly convert that data into a integer if it is not something that is like a number.